# Comparing two Bits type values in Chisel 3

Tags: chisel

I want to compare two Bits type values in chisel. First I tried this using === operator.

```
val byte = (typ === MT_B)
```

This gave the error "value === is not a member of chisel3.Bits". So I tried equals method as follows.

```
val byte    =   (typ.equals(MT_B))
```

And this gave the following error in a later part of the code where this byte value is used for the condition in a Mux.

```
found   : Boolean
[error]  required: chisel3.core.Bool
[error]         val dout    =   Mux(byte, Fill(4, din( 7,0)),
```

I can't find a way to convert the Boolean return of equals method to Bool typer for the Mux. And I couldn't find a substitute for the === operator from chisel 3 API ethier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Boolean** is a Scala literal. The Chisel equivalent is **Bool**.

Cast into a Chisel Bool like this

```
val myBoolean = true // Scala literal
val myBool = Bool(myBoolean)
```

Alternatively, you can also use **myBoolean.B** to cast from Scala Boolean to Chisel Bool.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. However, why did they remove === operator from Bits type in chisel 3? As far as I know it was there in chisel 2. And, isn't there any way to directly get a Bool type from Bits comparison now? Something like that would reduce the code clutter.

Comment: I just tested the === operator on two values of the Bits type in a simple design. It works for me. And yes, you can get a Bool value from a compare operation by appending a ".toBool()". If you'd like a more detailed explanation, maybe post a new question.

Comment: Bits still has === in Chisel 3. Also, all comparison operators in Chisel return a Bool. I'm curious to see how you are getting this error that "value === is not a member of chisel3.Bits" because I cannot reproduce it.